# Stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am running the following command in PHPMyAdmin:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE addid()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE a,b FLOAT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE c,d INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT time FROM results;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

OPEN cur1;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    IF a - b > 60 THEN 
      SET c = c+1;
    ELSE
      UPDATE results SET uid=c WHERE time=a;
    END IF;
    SET b = a;
  END LOOP;
CLOSE cur1;
END#
DELIMITER ;
CALL addid();
```

Maybe it will do what I want, maybe not. But I don't know because I can't call it.

I get the following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOOP; CLOSE cur1; END# call addid()' at line 20
```

Sometime, depending on how I tweak it, I can get the create to run but then it cant find the stored procedure, like it just does not get made.

This is my first time ever using stored procedures so it's probably something stupid. I'm running MySQL 5.0.7.

Comment: What happens if you include the loop label at the end statement?  `END LOOP read_loop;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just now I saw what seems to be the problem in your code....

```
IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;
```

The endif is missing.

Comment: Ten seconds on Google would have led you to the [LEAVE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/leave-statement.html) documentation.

Comment: And ten more seconds cdhowie would have led you to more intelligent voting. Hopefully you will be smart enough to up vote.

Comment: FYI cdhowie..... From the official source.... When should I vote down?

Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Comment: When hovering over the downvote, the tooltip says "this answer is not useful."  It was indeed not useful in any way.  Now that you've found the real problem (the missing `END IF`) I've edited out the incorrect part of your answer and converted to an upvote.

Comment: Yep, it was the end if. Thanks!